# Filling in LogLogPlot

Tags: plotting, graphics, filling

I have a function `firsttempinterp[x]` that I plot using `LogLogPlot`. I used `Filling` to fill a region with gray color, however, using `PlotRangePadding` does not cover the entire region I want. The region is above the curve until the y-axis to the left. Any guide on how to resolve this?

```
temp = {0.1, 0.1355, 0.5, 10};
firsttime = {0.21707, 0.23616, 0.44440, 6.47129};
firsttempdata = Transpose[{firsttime, temp}];
firsttempinterp = 
  Interpolation[
    firsttempdata, 
    InterpolationOrder -> 2, 
    Method -> "Spline"
  ]

LogLogPlot[{
  If[x < 0.23616 + 3 2.361387, firsttempinterp[x - 3 2.361387] + 3 1.355, None],
  If[x > 0.23616 + 3 2.361387, firsttempinterp[x - 3 2.361387] + 3 1.355, None]},
  {x, 0, 17}, 
  Frame -> True,
  FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 20],
  PlotStyle -> {{Dashed, Black, Thick}, {Black, Thick}},
  PlotRange -> {All, {0.09, 10.5}}, 
  PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
  Filling -> {
     1 -> {Top, {Directive[Opacity[0.3], Gray]}},
     2 -> {Top, {Directive[Opacity[0.3], Gray]}}
  },
  ImageSize -> Large
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
LogLogPlot[Max[.09, firsttempinterp[x - 3 2.361387] + 3 1.355], {x, 0, 17}, 
 Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 20], 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black], 
 PlotRange -> {All, {0.09, 10.5}}, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
 Filling -> Top,
 FillingStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.3], Gray], 
 ImageSize -> Large, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, 
 Mesh -> {{.09, 3 1.355}}, 
 MeshStyle -> None,
 MeshShading -> {None, Dashed, Dashing[{}]}, 
 PlotPoints -> 200, MaxRecursion -> 7]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

With your definitions, add a gray background to the whole plot to represent your desired filling, then use an actual filling directive, using opaque white, to fill the part under the curve that should look "unfilled". The changes in your code are highlighted below between empty lines:

```
LogLogPlot[{
  If[x < 0.23616 + 3 2.361387, firsttempinterp[x - 3 2.361387] + 3 1.355, None],
  If[x > 0.23616 + 3 2.361387, firsttempinterp[x - 3 2.361387] + 3 1.355, None]},
  {x, 0, 17}, 
  Frame -> True,
  FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 20],
  PlotStyle -> {{Dashed, Black, Thick}, {Black, Thick}},
  PlotRange -> {All, {0.09, 10.5}}, 
  PlotRangePadding -> 0, 

  Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> White,
  Prolog -> {
    Opacity[0.3, Gray],
    Rectangle[Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{1, 1}]]
  },

  ImageSize -> Large
]
```

[image: new plot with desired gray filling on left and top]

Answer (score 3):

Add a fake function:

```
Exp[x - 1.2] == 100
```

to your existing plot and adjust the constant as you see fit.

```
LogLogPlot[
 {If[x < 0.23616 + 3 2.361387,
   firsttempinterp[x - 3 2.361387] + 3 1.355, None],
  If[x > 0.23616 + 3 2.361387,
   firsttempinterp[x - 3 2.361387] + 3 1.355, None],
  Exp[x - 1.2] == 100
  }
 , {x, 0, 17}
 , Frame -> True
 , FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 20]
 , PlotStyle -> {
   {Dashed, Black, Thick}
   , {Black, Thick}
   , {Dotted, Thin, Red}
   }
 , PlotRange -> {{0.1, 12}, {0.09, 10.5}}
 , PlotRangePadding -> 0
 , Filling -> {
   1 -> {Top, {Directive[Opacity[0.3], Gray]}}
   , 2 -> {Top, {Directive[Opacity[0.3], Blue]}}
   , 3 -> {Top, {Directive[Opacity[0.3], Pink]}}
   }
 , ImageSize -> Large,
 AspectRatio -> 0.75
 ]
```

I am showing the three colored regions, that you can revert to `Gray`.

[image]

Comment: One word, clever! Thanks!

Comment: Just last question, if I want to change `firsttempinterp[x - 3 2.361387] + 3 1.355` to `firsttempinterp[x - 2.361387] + 1.355`, how should I control `Exp[x - 1.2] == 100` so that there is no overlapping red/gray region? I'm trying to change `1.2` and `100` to some other values but the curve `Exp[x - 1.2] == 100` overlaps a little bit on the top portion and has a gap on the bottom region.

Comment: If your requirements are changing, then I would advise you to accept the other answer and unaccept this one. It is a better solution.